# Bootstrap DataTable Sparkline not working if Table set to Responsive

Tags: javascript, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5, sparklines

I have a Bootstrap DataTable with a sparkline in the last column, here is the full js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var groupColumn = 0;

  let table = $('#example').DataTable({
    //responsive: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    processing: true,
    ordering: true,
    scrollY: '50vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
    searching: true,

    ajax: {
      url: "api/ApartmentsAvailables",
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
    },
    columnDefs: [{
        visible: false,
        targets: groupColumn
      },
      {
        targets: 7,
        render: DataTable.render.datetime('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00', 'MMMM D, YYYY', 'en'),
      },
      {
        responsivePriority: 1,
        targets: 0
      },
    ],
    order: [
      [groupColumn, 'asc']
    ],

    drawCallback: function(settings) {
      $('.sparkline')
        .map(function() {
          return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
        })
        .sparkline('html', {
          type: 'line',
          width: '250px'
        })

      var api = this.api();
      var rows = api.rows({
        page: 'current'
      }).nodes();
      var last = null;

      api
        .column(groupColumn, {
          page: 'current'
        })
        .data()
        .each(function(group, i) {
          if (last !== group) {
            $(rows)
              .eq(i)
              .before('<tr class="group" style="background-color:DarkGray; text-align:center;font-weight: bold; color:white;"><td  colspan="8">' + group + '</td></tr>');

            last = group;
          }
        })
    },
    columns: [

      {
        data: "building"
      },
      {
        data: "floor_Plan"
      },
      {
        data: "apt_Number"
      },
      {
        data: "rent"
      },
      {
        data: "bedrooms"
      },
      {
        data: "bathrooms"
      },
      {
        data: "sqft"
      },
      {
        data: "available_Date"
      },
      {
        data: 'prices',
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {

          return type === 'display' ?
            '<span class="sparkline">' + data.toString() + '</span>' :
            data;
        }
      },
    ]
  });
  new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
  // Order by the grouping
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function() {
    var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
    if (currentOrder[0] === groupColumn && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
      table.order([groupColumn, 'desc']).draw();
    } else {
      table.order([groupColumn, 'asc']).draw();
    }
  });
});
```

The problem occurs when I enable `responsive: true`, the sparkline column becomes hidden and when I click to expand the row to show the hidden columns it shows the whole array of Value and not the sparkline.

I guess that the

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
            $('.sparkline')
                .map(function () {
                    return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
                })
                .sparkline('html', {
                    type: 'line',
                    width: '250px'
                })
```

is not able to be applied to a column that is hidden.

Without the responsive option the HTML generated for the td is:

```
<td>
    <span class="sparkline">
        <canvas style="display: inline-block; width: 250px; height: 21px; vertical-align: top;"
                width="250"
                height="21"/>
    </span>
</td>
```

With the responsive set to true:

```
<td style="display: none;"
    class="dtr-hidden">
    <span class="sparkline">3446,3446,3416,3416,3416,3546,3546,3546,3546,3546,3546,3561,3556,3551,3396,3396,3396,3346,3306,3306,3306</span>
</td>
```

I presume that I should somehow capture the mouse click on the expand icon and then re-inject the canvas but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: There is no need to quote attributes unless they have special characters in them. Including them in content other than JSON is distracting.

Comment: I would try capturing the expand event and call the `drawCallback` code when it occurs.

Comment: Hello @HereticMonkey. Thanks for the answer. What quoted attributes are you referring to?
About the expand event can you give me some more detail? Thanks

Comment: I edited them out of your question. They were around `ajax` and all of its properties.

Comment: Ohhh! Yes sorry for that and thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an event you can use for that, provided as part of the DataTables Responsive extension:

[`responsive-display`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/responsive-display)

This event fires whenever...

> The details for a row have been displayed, updated or hidden.

So, for example, you can add the following to your script, and then place your standard sparklines logic in the event's function:

```js
table.on( 'responsive-display', function ( e, datatable, row, showHide, update )  {
    $('.sparkline')
      .map(function() {
        return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
      })
      .sparkline('html', {
        type: 'line',
        width: '250px'
      });
  } );
```

This will re-build your sparkline from the raw data.

---

You can see the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) for a list of all the events, API functions, and options available in the Responsive extension.

---

**Update**

"*not able to make it work...*"

Here is my runnable demo in case it helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stock_data = [
        {
            "name": "ACME Gadgets",
            "symbol": "AGDTS",
            "last": "2.57, 2.54, 2.54, 2.56, 2.57, 2.58, 2.59"
        },
        {
            "name": "Spry Media Productions",
            "symbol": "SPMP",
            "last": "1.12, 1.11, 1.08, 1.08, 1.09, 1.11, 1.08"
        },
        {
            "name": "Widget Emporium",
            "symbol": "WDEMP",
            "last": "3.40, 3.39, 3.46, 3.51, 3.50, 3.48, 3.49"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sole Goodman",
            "symbol": "SGMAN",
            "last": "16.20, 16.40, 16.36, 16.35, 16.61, 16.46, 16.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "Stanler Bits and Bobs",
            "symbol": "SBIBO",
            "last": "82.51, 83.47, 83.40, 83.68, 83.81, 83.29, 83.72"
        }
    ];
 
    let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        
        responsive: true,
    
        ajax: function(dataSent, callback, settings) {
            let data = this.api().ajax.json();
            if(data == undefined) {
                data = stock_data;
                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].last = data[i].last.split(",").map(element => {
                        return Number(element);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                data = data.data;
                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].last.push(data[i].last.shift())
                }
            }
            callback({data: data});
        },
        paging: false,
        initComplete: function() {
            let api = this.api();
            //setInterval(function() {
            //    api.ajax.reload();
            //}, 5000);
        },
        drawCallback: function() {
            $('.sparkline')
                .map(function() {
                    return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
                })
                .sparkline('html', {
                    type: 'line',
                    width: '250px'
                })
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'name'
            },
            {
                data: 'symbol'
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return row.last[row.last.length - 1].toFixed(2);
                }
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    var val = (row.last[row.last.length - 1] - row.last[row.last.length - 2]).toFixed(2);
                    var colour = val < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span style="color:' + colour + '">' + val + '</span>' :
                        val;
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'last',
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span class="sparkline">' + data.toString() + '</span>' :
                        data;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    
    
    table.on( 'responsive-display', function ( e, datatable, row, showHide, update ) {
      $('.sparkline')
        .map(function() {
          return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
        })
        .sparkline('html', {
          type: 'line',
          width: '250px'
        });
    } );
    
    
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>  
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sparklines/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
  
    <!-- responsive plug-in -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/css/responsive.dataTables.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Difference</th>
                <th>Last</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Difference</th>
                <th>Last</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I don't have the + and - icons, so you just have to click on the cell instead, to show/hide data.

I also commented out the `setInterval` function, as that causes the display to be reset every 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you @andrewJames , I was actlayy able to achive the same result using this:
```$('#example').on('click', 'tr td.dtr-control', function (event) {
        // Expand row details
        $('.sparkline')
            .map(function () {
                return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
            })
            .sparkline('html', {
                type: 'line',
                width: '250px'
            })
    });```
But I would try now also the official solution!

Comment: That's great! - but make sure that works in all possible scenarios: (a) when someone clicks on the "show/hide" button and also (b) when someone makes the browser window wider and narrower, by dragging it; and also (c) doing combinations of (a) and (b). If it works for all situations, then you can add your approach as another official answer.

Comment: actually I was just doing that and changing the size of the window will not re-apply the canvas to the numbers list come back up and you need to click again on a row to let the magic happen, so my solution is not that strong.

Comment: On the other hand I was trying the official event function but I'm not able to make it work

Comment: I added my full demo, in case that helps.

Comment: Yeah... I don't know what I did wrong earlier... probably copied/pasted over something else.. but now it's working. Just a small issue... when I put the mouse over the sparkline the small label that should appear with the value in that position is like half size of what it should be so I can rad only the bottom part of the number... your demo is not doing that... not sure what can affect it...

Comment: Found it. 
```element {
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}```
that box-sizing is doing it